# Scaling issues with scipy.sparse matrix while using scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

While solving a machine learning problem using scikit-learn I need to do scaling of scipy.sparse matrix before doing the training using SVM. But in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing) it is clearly mentioned that:

> scale and StandardScaler accept scipy.sparse matrices as input only when with_mean=False is explicitly passed to the constructor. Otherwise a ValueError will be raised as silently centering would break the sparsity and would often crash the execution by allocating excessive amounts of memory unintentionally.

This means that I cannot have zero mean with this. So how do I scale this sparse matrix so that it has zero mean too along with unit variance? I also need to store this 'scaling' so that I can use the same transformation on the test matrix to scale it as well.

Answer (score 9):

If the matrix is small, you can densify it with `X.toarray()`. If the matrix is large, then this will probably blow your RAM.

As an alternative to mean-centering and scaling, you can try per-sample normalization with `sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer`; this is appropriate for frequency features (e.g. in text classification).

Comment: My matrix is very large (500000 X 40000), hence I cannot do toarray thing. And the normalizer does sample by sample scaling which means all the data points wont be scaled uniformly, hence I can't use it. Still, figuring out a way to do this. Looks like I will have to write a script of my own to do this.

Comment: @VineetChirania: what does the data represent? (You probably won't be able to fit a non-linear SVM to that amount of data anyway because the SVM training algorithm takes cubic time.)

Comment: I tried using svm with linear kernel but it took huge time in learning. So I am now using LinearSVC which is based on liblinear instead of libsvm. 
If I don't do mean-centering, just the scaling then does this affect the accuracy?