# Centering Sparse Data for SVM

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I learned that when you run SVMs, you should center the data and normalize components to unit variance. However, my original data is very sparse and pre-processing my data in this way makes it dense. It seems that this makes my model train very slowly. How would you deal with this, if you are using off the shelf implementations of SVM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling issues with scipy.sparse matrix while using scikit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240068/scaling-issues-with-scipy-sparse-matrix-while-using-scikit)

Comment: Preprocess data dynamically in the SVM code per instance so that you can keep your memory fair with a little execution sot.you can also consider to use another model like RandomForests.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to scale that way. You could either just scale, without centering, or just divide by the absolute maximum to get your data to be in the range -1 and 1.